# What is the name of this multiplicative tensor operation that can retrieve components?

Tags: notation, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I know this might be somewhat of a dumb question, but I've discovered a neat way to represent the components of a (assume real valued) tensor via a sort of "multiplication". Let's say I have a real $(0,2)$ tensor (order $2$) of dimension $2$:
$$\mathbf{T} =\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
T_{1,1} & T_{1,2}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
T_{2,1} & T_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since this is a $(0,2)$ tensor, I right "*multiply*" by $2$ contravariant basis vectors to retrieve components. For example if I want the component $T_{1,2}$ I take the right product with $\underline{e_1}$ and $\underline{e_2}$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
T_{1,1} & T_{1,2}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
T_{2,1} & T_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
T_{1,1} & T_{1,2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}=T_{1,2}$$
Which follows the usual standards of "matrix" multiplication. Another example: Supposing we have a $(2,1)$ tensor (order $3$) of dimension $2$:
$$\mathbf{T} =\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
T^{1,1}_{1}\\
T^{1,2}_{1}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
T^{1,1}_{2}\\
T^{1,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
T^{2,1}_{1}\\
T^{2,2}_{1}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
T^{2,1}_{2}\\
T^{2,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since this is a $(2,1)$ tensor I left multiply by two covariant basis vectors and right multiply by one contravariant basis vector. Say if I want to retrieve $T^{2,1}_2$ - Then I can left multiply by $\underline{\epsilon^2}$ and $\underline{\epsilon^1}$ (the dual space basis) and right multiply by $\underline{e_2}$ (Notice that the order we write the covectors is opposite to their index order so that the order of *multiplication* matches the index order)
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
T^{1,1}_{1}\\
T^{1,2}_{1}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
T^{1,1}_{2}\\
T^{1,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
T^{2,1}_{1}\\
T^{2,2}_{1}
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
T^{2,1}_{2}\\
T^{2,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
T^{1,1}_{2}\\
T^{1,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}
T^{2,1}_{2}\\
T^{2,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
T^{2,1}_{2}\\
T^{2,2}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}=T^{2,1}_{2}$$
My question is: **is there a name for this operation?** It really resembles matrix multiplication but isn't, since the item in the middle isn't a matrix - it is a tensor that I have simply "projected down" so it is readable on a 2D screen. **Is there any special notation for this operation?**

Thanks for your time,

-K. defaoite

Comment: . . . projectors

Comment: @janmarqz Care to elaborate?

Comment: do you know that if $f,g$ are covectors (linear functionals) of $V$ then the matrix associated to the rank two tensor $f\otimes g$ is such that its entries are $f\otimes g(b_i,b_j)=f(b_i)g(b_j)$, where the $b_s$ generate the vector space?

Comment: @janmarqz I did not know this. Is there any literature on the topic you can point me to?

Comment: these notes https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2016/other/mla/ma.pdf are good but not perfect... also give, to my post on the subject, a glimpse